# Wordpress Login not working with email address

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

on my wordpress site when i clicked on "My Account" link at that time it will me display login page . Currently it's fine .

my problem is when i login with my email address at that time it display me error check below screen shot .

[image]

it just working with the username not in email address and also it says "username and email" .

How can i fix this issue please help me anyone ...

Many thanks

Comment: Are you sure you're using the correct e-mail address?

Comment: yes Roman it's fine .

Comment: if you want to login with email id instead of username then use following plugin.
https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-email-login/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to use a plugin, you can add the following to your functions.php file it will allow you to login with the username **or** email address:

```
// remove the default filter
remove_filter( 'authenticate', 'wp_authenticate_username_password', 20, 3 );
// add custom filter
add_filter( 'authenticate', 'fb_authenticate_username_password', 20, 3 );
function fb_authenticate_username_password( $user, $username, $password ) {

// If an email address is entered in the username box, 
// then look up the matching username and authenticate as per normal, using that.
if ( ! empty( $username ) )
    $user = get_user_by( 'email', $username );

if ( isset( $user->user_login, $user ) )
    $username = $user->user_login;

// using the username found when looking up via email
return wp_authenticate_username_password( NULL, $username, $password );
}
```

(The above was found [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/51714) and I tested it and worked for me)

Answer (score 0):

1. Are you able to login using:

   http://wwww.yourwebsite.com/wp-login.php

Yes?
This is probably a theme setting. Check your theme settings for changing the login method by e-mail.

No?
- Check your wp_users table in your database and make sure your e-mail adress is correct.

Comment: Hi i don't use any custom theme . just use default wordpress theme and i am login with wocommerce my account page . thanks